# Java cache library mapdb expire max size

Tags: java, caching, mapdb

I'd like to use **mapdb** library to cache max n object. I wrote something like this:

```
DB dbMemory = DBMaker
              .memoryDB()
              .make();

HTreeMap<Long, String> inMemory = dbMemory
              .hashMap("inMemory", Serializer.LONG, Serializer.STRING)
              .expireMaxSize(2)
              .create();

inMemory.put((long)1, "1");
inMemory.put((long)2, "2");
inMemory.put((long)3, "3");
inMemory.put((long)4, "4");

inMemory.getValues().forEach(val -> System.out.println(val));
```

My expected result should be just:

```
3
4
```

But I got (not always in this order):

```
1
2
3
4
```

I am sure that it just my misunderstanding of using this library so could someone show me what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [HTreeMap documentation](https://jankotek.gitbooks.io/mapdb/content/htreemap/) says:

> Time based eviction will always place entry into Expiration Queue. But
>   other expiration criteria (size and space limit) also needs hint when
>   to place entry into Expiration Queue. In following example no entry is
>   placed into queue and no entry ever expires.
>
> ```
> HTreeMap cache = db
>     .hashMap("cache")
>     .expireMaxSize(1000)
>     .create();
> ```

So you need to add a hint. The documentation further says:

> There are three possible triggers which will place entry into Expiration Queue: `expireAfterCreate()`, `expireAfterUpdate()` and `expireAfterGet()`.

Add those - you probably want the create and update hints.